# What's the best way to fiil list <string>?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method, the input of which is a list of file addresses that I want to open this files and process it. this address contains the file extension. I know for sure that I have 3 file extensions (txt, xlsx, xls)

in the code pathWithFilesName it input list with file path;

then I want to send them to methods that will open and process them

```
        pathWithFilesName.Add("ds.xlsx");
        pathWithFilesName.Add("ds.txt");
        var listExcel=new List<string>();
        var listTxt= new List<string>();
        var validExcelFileTypes = new List<string>{ ".xls", ".xlsx" };

        foreach (var path in pathWithFilesName)
        {
            foreach (var valid in validExcelFileTypes)
            {
                if (path.EndsWith(valid))
                {
                    listExcel.Add(path);
                }
                else
                {
                    listTxt.Add(path);
                }
            }
        }
```

this variant not optimal at all but work)
i know how take excel files on link

```
var list= (from path in pathWithFilesName from valid in validExcelFileTypes where path.EndsWith(valid) select path).ToList();
```

but with this approach I need then compare 2 lists. for example some kind of Intersect

what is the best way to make a sample?

Comment: `pathWithFilesName.Where(path=>validExcelFileTypes.Any(ext=> path.EndsWith(ext)))`

Comment: Speaking of optimal your variant is not bad. not at all you enumerate the main source only once. We are doing the same thing.

Comment: You will find that "SplitOn" extention  will be either using 2 foreach or an aggregate.

Comment: What are your criteria for "best"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a variation using LinQ and lambda. It should not be more efficient not better or worse. It may be more readable.

The `listExcel` can be find that way :

```
var listExcel = pathWithFilesName.Where(path=>validExcelFileTypes.Any(ext=> path.EndsWith(ext)));
```

- [Enumerable.Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0)
- [Enumerable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0)

If you need both list in one go. You can group the source on the same condition:

```
var listGrp = pathWithFilesName.GroupBy(path=>validExcelFileTypes.Any(ext=> path.EndsWith(ext)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MoreLinQ `Partition`: "*Partitions a sequence **by a predicate**,..*".

```
var (listExcel, listTxt) = pathWithFilesName
                                  .Partition(p => 
                                      validExcelFileTypes.Any(ext => p.EndsWith(ext)) 
                                  );
```

Under the hood it's just a `GroupBy` [source code](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Partition.cs#L78).  Unrolled into a Named Tuple.

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lm61kQ)